# Tkinter throws ImportError

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to make my first Tkinter project in Python but it just shows me this:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am using Arch.

I have tried `pip install tkinter` but it didn't help.

Pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `# pacman -S tk` I had the same problem and that fixed it.